# Delete everything before last / in a file path

Tags: bash, filepath

I have many file paths in a file that look like so:

```
/home/rtz11/files/testfiles/547/prob547455_01
```

I want to use a bash script that will print all the filenames to the screen, basically whatever comes after the last `/`.  I don't want to assume that it would always be the same length because it might not be.

Would there be a way to delete everything before the last `/`? Maybe a `sed` command?

Comment: Do you _also_ want to delete the last `/`, or only content prior to it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
awk '{print $NF}' FS=/ input-file
```

The 'print $NF' directs awk to print the last field of each line, and assigning FS=/ makes forward slash the field delimeter.  In sed, you could do:

```
sed 's@.*/@@' input-file
```

which simply deletes everything up to and including the last `/`.

Comment: Note that the at sign `@` is merely [used here as a delimiter](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-2), replacing the usual forward slash `/`.  The latter cannot be readily employed because it constitutes the target. Equivalent commands would be `sed s|.*/||'` or `sed 's:.*/::'`.

Answer (score 44):

Using `sed` for this is vast overkill -- bash has extensive string manipulation built in, and using this built-in support is far more efficient when operating on only a single line.

```
s=/home/rtz11/files/testfiles/547/prob547455_01
basename="${s##*/}"
echo "$basename"
```

This will remove everything from the beginning of the string greedily matching `*/`. See [the bash-hackers wiki entry for parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

---

If you only want to remove everything *prior to* the last `/`, but not including it (a literal reading of your question, but also a generally less useful operation), you might instead want `if [[ $s = */* ]]; then echo "/${s##*/}"; else echo "$s"; fi`.

Comment: Excellent resource. Side note, if you need the Path to a file use `${PATHNAME%/*}`.

Answer (score 3):

Meandering but simply because I can remember the syntax I use:

```
cat file | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev
```

Many ways to skin a 'cat'.  Ouch.

Comment: This is way too expensive, though it does the job well.

Answer (score 0):

One more way:

*Use the basename executable (command):*

```
basename /path/with/many/slashes/and/file.extension
```

`>file.extension`

```
basename /path/with/many/slashes/and/file.extension .extension
```

OR

```
basename -s .extension /path/with/many/slashes/and/file.extension
```

`> file`